# Advanced Rigging For Robot Arms/ legs IK

Tags: rigging, armature

I build a Robot working on Gears, Chains and Pistons and I'm trying to rig it with IK for the legs and Arms but I'm stuck.
the arm/Leg is supposed to work as such:

- first part(shoulders) need to rotate around itself only
- Second part (ArmTop) need to rotate at Z pose only
- third part (ArmBTM) need to rotate around himself only
- forth and fifth part (Arm and forearm) is the IK

When the 1,2,3 parts need to follow the IK So if The Arm wave Hello for example :

- first part will rotate a bit
- second will rotate up
- third will rotate as the arm

if it was in FK it was (1=Y19.5 / 2=Z-119 / 3=Y-70 / 4=X-25 / 5=X-12)(the last picture)

I don't know how to add a file so if you want the Robot file for you to try on it explain how to upload file on here and i will add it

[image: FrontView]
[image: SideView]
[image: WithoutExtras]
[image: SayHay]

if there is anything you can help
Thanks A head
Omer

Comment: Can't you just use locks?

Comment: locks dosn't work on IK  and lock constrain dosn't do what i want if the IK move above some hights  and i dont know how to lock with scripting

Answer (score 6):

when you have an bone set to use an IK constraint, every bone in that chain enables the Inverse Kinematics tab, found in the bone properties (almost down the bottom)

Here you can set limits on the XYZ axis of each bone. the X and Z axis limits show up in the display as a red and blue circle. Y doesnt show up as Y is rotation along the axis of the bone.

using axis limits does cause some popping, so you will want to use a Pole target for the IK constraint to allow better control.

[image]

[image]