# Complete noob wants to rig a 2 piece armature

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm completely new to Blender and I'd like to learn the very basics of rigging.

My final goal is to rig a 6 axis industrial robot and then export it to UE4, the problem is that I have knowledge in 3d modeling on industrial cads, and medium knowledge of programming and C++, but basically 0 knowledge of both UE4 and Blender....

I want to start with a very simple task (not simple at all at the moment for me):
Import only 2 parts of the robot in blender through .stl format, and learn how to rig them properly.

These 2 parts have to rotate on a single axis like in picture.

[image: parts]

Could you at least provide me with a list of things I have to learn in order to reach this goal? I am totally lost right now :D

Sadly I can only import the 2 parts at the moment, but, they seem to be already in the correct spot when I import them, so I wonder if that might help somehow in the process.

[image: blender]

Comment: maybe follow this kind of tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsFFlHbUJT0

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31320/advanced-rigging-for-robot-arms-legs-ik

Comment: Here is a mini-series about rigging for beginners https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cxlPWv9giR4&list=PLL3OEv6vd5VCrqZiupP2m68qSWHYAjoiW

Comment: For the mesh you're demonstrating, you need to learn how to 1) import .stl 2) delete parts of your mesh 3) create an armature 4) separate meshes into separate objects 5) parent objects to bone.  Each of those is pretty much a single sentence to describe.